# filter aggregation not working elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data

I am trying to use filter aggregation to support multi-select facet values from the frontend.

I have color and depth filters.

color filter holds values: black(5),blue(3),red(2)

depth filter holds values: 70mm(3),60mm(5),50mm(3)

When I select the Black in the color filter all other options(blue, red) not coming in response.

I have tried by adding

```
"colourAgg": {
        "filter": {
            "match_all": {
                "boost": 1.0
            }
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "colourAgg": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "colour.keyword",
                    "size": 10,
                    "min_doc_count": 1,
                    "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                    "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                    "order": [
                        {
                            "_count": "desc"
                        },
                        {
                            "_key": "asc"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Mapping:

```
{
"products": {
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "assemblyrequired": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "australianmade": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "australiasellable": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "avgRating": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "category": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "categorylevel1": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "categorylevel2": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "categorylevel3": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "categoryname": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "colour": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "commercialuse": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "customisable": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "depth": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "freedelivery": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "height": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "listprice": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "materialcode": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "moneybackguarantee": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "newrelease": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "numberOfRating": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "online": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "outdooruse": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "predictivecategorydata": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "pricematchguarantee": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "productid": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "productimageurl": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "productname": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "producttypecode": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "promotedprice": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "sale": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "saleprice": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "sellable": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "sellercode": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "shortdescription": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "sku": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "state": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "stylecode": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "warrantycode": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "weight": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "width": {
                "type": "float"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Document:

```
{
                "sellercode": "F2OVRX",
                "productid": 13410,
                "saleprice": 4000.2,
                "producttypecode": "Recliner Lounge or Sofa",
                "productimageurl": null,
                "sellable": false,
                "freedelivery": false,
                "promotedprice": null,
                "listprice": 4000.2,
                "productname": "louise chair - cream",
                "outdooruse": null,
                "avgRating": 0.0,
                "warrantycode": null,
                "state": [
                    "SA",
                    "NT"
                ],
                "newrelease": null,
                "sku": "VSTALDBED415_8",
                "height": 66.0,
                "shortdescription": "Stackable light weight chair made from Virgin materials.High strength one piece gas injection moulded technology.160kg weight tested, Catas test certificated",
                "commercialuse": true,
                "customisable": true,
                "weight": null,
                "pricematchguarantee": true,
                "colour": "Black",
                "australianmade": true,
                "depth": 65.0,
                "moneybackguarantee": false,
                "width": 31.0,
                "predictivecategorydata": [
                    "Dressing Table-Dining Table-52"
                ],
                "online": true,
                "materialcode": "Timber",
                "numberOfRating": 0,
                "categoryname": [
                    "Bed - Double",
                    "Dining Table",
                    "Dressing Table",
                    "444",
                    "Bench",
                    null,
                    "M13",
                    "Bed Head"
                ],
                "location": [],
                "assemblyrequired": null,
                "category": [
                    "outdoor",
                    "bed",
                    "doublebeds",
                    "444",
                    "beds",
                    "cat1220",
                    "m13",
                    "cafebarrestaurant"
                ],
                "stylecode": "Safari"
            }
```

but still I am getting black only.Any inputs?

Thanks,
Sree.

Comment: Please add mapping and one sample result

Comment: @KartikPuri added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation processes documents returned by "query" part. So if you are filtering on "black" in query, all documents with color black will be returned and aggregation will get applied on these docs .

You need your aggregation to apply on all documents in index, not just those returned by query. You can use [Global aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation.html) for this

> Defines a single bucket of all the documents within the search
>   execution context. This context is defined by the indices and the
>   document types you’re searching on, but is not influenced by the
>   search query itself.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "products": {
      "global": {}, --> note
      "aggs": {
        "filtered_docs": {   --> filter certain docs for entire index 
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "depth": {
                "gte": 60
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "colourAgg": {   --> facets for color
              "terms": {
                "field": "colour.keyword",
                "size": 10,
                "min_doc_count": 1,
                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                "order": [
                  {
                    "_count": "desc"
                  },
                  {
                    "_key": "asc"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, If I try with global aggregation, the other filters are not applying. Suppose If select depth as 70mm then the related colors should available. So that I can do a multi-select on the available colors.

Comment: @sree you only need select filters(not all) to apply for aggregation correct?/

Comment: Yes @jaspreet Chahal

Comment: added the sample document and mapping

Comment: thanks.I will convert that to java and test..Meanwhile can you please add the explanation on the query?.Struggling to understand the query

Comment: I am not able to find any document related to filtered_docs. Can you help on this please

Comment: @sree filtered_docs is name of aggregation , same as colourAgg , aggregation type is "filter". https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212953/discussion-between-sree-and-jaspreet-chahal).